# Graphic novel about a girl and a mischievous green man/creature that only she can see

Tags: story-identification, graphic-novel

This was a graphic novel that I read back in the 2010s when I was a kid, so my memory might be foggy.

I know for a fact that it was about this teenage girl and a weird creature that sort of followed her around, I think maybe only she could see him. Pretty sure the comic was in greyscale except for the creature, who was light green. He was man-shaped, skinny with big ears and a long nose, very goblinish. He did not wear clothes lol. He and the girl also did NOT get along, he annoyed her a lot from what I can remember.

There are some scenes I can recall, like one where the goblin man eats some sort of porridge/stew from a bowl. Another where the girl tries to put the creature in a closet, or maybe he was hiding from her in a closet? And I think there was a scene where they are both in a shopping mall, and a fire escape and dumpster are involved in some way. The girl's friends also got mad at her at some point, because she was being weird due to the strange green goblin man hanging around her.

Thanks for anyone who can understand this. Would love it if someone knew what I was talking about! It was a weird comic, and I did not understand it back then!

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description, it sounds like you might be referring to "I Kill Giants" by Joe Kelly and J.M. Ken Niimura. The graphic novel was published in 2008. The main character is a young girl named Barbara Thorson, who is dealing with some personal issues and imagines a giant creature as a way to cope. The story is in black and white, but the giant creature is portrayed in a different color? maybe. And if so possibly the light green you mentioned.

Comment: _"the giant creature is portrayed in a different color? maybe. And if so possibly the light green you mentioned."_ You don't sound very sure about this part. Have you actually read this story? Also, the [Goodreads summary](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28020070-i-kill-giants-1) doesn't sound like a good match to the OP's description; the OP never said anything about the creature being a giant, or the girl being a giant-slayer.

Comment: @LogicDictates I had read it a long time ago, OP's writings brought this graphic novel to my mind, and I don't remember some details clearly, so my sentence contained hesitation. By the way, isn't the purpose of this Stack Exchange to inform the other party about what they may not remember correctly? If we assume all of OP's writings are correct, wouldn't the likelihood of finding it decrease?

Comment: I have to agree with @LogicDictates. It's not a very good match.